# Could someone explain these codes for me (about JavaScript and HTML5)?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script>
    window.BlobBuilder = window.BlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder;

    Blob.prototype.slice = Blob.prototype.slice || function(start, length) {
        return this.webkitSlice(start, start + length);
    }

</script>
```

These codes are from a background page of a Chrome extension. Any idea or hint will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
window.BlobBuilder = window.BlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder;
```

this says set `window.BlobBuilder` to what it is already set to if whatever it is set to is truthy; if whatever it's set to currently is falsey, then set it to `window.WebKitBlobBuilder`. This is a general approach used to assign a value to a variable if it doesn't already have a truthy value. Truthy values are anything that are not falsey values, and the falsey values are

- `null`
- `undefined`
- `false`
- `''`
- `0`
- `NaN`

The next line uses similar syntax

```
Blob.prototype.slice = Blob.prototype.slice || function(start, length) {
    return this.webkitSlice(start, start + length);
}
```

This sets the `slice` function on the `Blob` prototype object either to itself if the current value is truthy, or to a function that will use the `webkitSlice` function defined on `this` (which I assume will be `WebKitBlobBuilder` in this instance).

Answer (score 1):

My skin-deep understanding:

`window` is a object represents an open window/tab in a browser. For more information, see *window object section* in w3schools.com

`window.BlobBuilder` means `BlobBuilder` is a method of the object `window`, and it's used to create a `blob`, which is a object used to reference binary data in web applications.
http://code.google.com/apis/gears/api_blob.html
http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/#dfn-Blob

These lines are used to define methods/functions `window.BlobBuilder` and `Blob.prototype.slice` so that they are compatible with different web browsers, which may have different names or no name for  `window.BlobBuilder` and `Blob.prototype.slice`. For example, `window.WebKitBlobBuilder` replaces `window.BlobBuilder` in Chrome 12 or higher.